# Combining image gallery and iframe content with Fancy Box version 2

Tags: jquery, iframe, gallery, fancybox

is it possible to start a fancy box gallery with some pictures and also include content per iframe? An example:

```
<div id="1">
    <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="http://picture.com/pic1.jpg" title="title">
        <p>pic1</p>
    </a>
</div>

<div id="2">
    <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="http://picture.com/pic2.jpg" title="title">
        <p>pic2</p>
    </a>
</div>

<div id="3">
    <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="http://website.com" title="title">
        <p>pic1</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

If you click on the second picture `Next` I would like to load `website.com` in an `iframe`.

Answer (score 1):

sure you can, just add the class "fancybox.iframe" to the  anchor that opens the html site so

your code:

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="http://website.com" title="title">
```

should be:

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" rel="gallery1" href="http://website.com" title="title">
```

Comment: Ohhh, yes quite easy. Thank you very much.